# multiple table join optimizing performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a project that uses a database with a user and a contact table.  They look like below:

```
UserTable:
    UserID     FirstName     LastName
    1          John          Smith
    2          Ted           Raimi
    3          Brian          Park

ContactTable:
    ContactID     UserID     ContactType   PhoneNum
    1             1          Home          5555555555
    2             1          Work          4444444444
    3             2          Home          3333333333
```

and a sample right join for this table would be

```
UserID     FirstName     ContactID     ContactType   PhoneNum
1          John          1             Home          5555555555
1          John          2             Work          4444444444
2          Ted           3             Home          3333333333
3          Brian
```

my C# business objects looks like:

```
public class User
{
     public int UserID{get;set;}
     public string FirstName{get;set;}
     public string LastName{get;set;}
     public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}
}
public class Contact
{
     public int ContactID{get;set;}
     public int UserID{get;set;}
     public string ContactType{get;set;}
     public string PhoneNum{get;set;}
}
```

so my question is:  What is the best way to combine this data?  Should i

1)do it through SQL, and perhaps use a PIVOT or CONCAT to merge the John Smiths into 1 row and then from the datatable output manage that to fit my objects? This would mean the output might look like:

```
UserID     FirstName     HomePhoneNum     WorkPhoneNum
1          John          5555555555       4444444444
2          Ted           3333333333
3          Brian
```

I would lose data this way (contactID), and it would be a pain to scale

2) Make multiple SQL calls instead of just 1?  When i make a list of 'users', i must also make a list of 'contacts', and then join them up through code?

3) Use just 1 SQL call, the original right join, and through LINQ goodness do a select distinct on users and use the applicable rows to fill out it's contact data?

I'm leaning towards #2, but i wanted to make sure i'm not missing another option. I feel like making the SQL statement more complicated (#1) is a bad idea, but i'm worried about the processing time for #2 and #3 when the user table gets large.  Does anyone have any suggestions for the best path forward?

Comment: I would use an ORM (ServiceStack, Fluent NHibernate, Entity framework, ...) and call it like `var users = repo.GetAll().Where( ... );` and then in a `foreach` you can access `user.Contacts`... but never ever... plain SQL ! Let the ORM deal with that, and you can always optimize through setup options several parameters like Lazyness to then perform a bit faster or not... ORM also takes care of query caching, so next user would not fetch from the db but use the previous values for example...

Comment: 1) Do you always want to fetch the entire contents of those tables, and 2) Is it safe to assume that every user will only have a few contacts, if any?

Comment: Because @Dave comment I have to ask. How you fill your class from db. Do you use Entity Framework?

Comment: @Juan, i don't use entity framework.  I use Dapper for some of my calls, and then my own explicit calls for everything else that dapper doesn't work for

Comment: @Biscuits:  both good questions.  I won't won't all the data all the time, but most of the time unfortunately.  Everyone should have 1 entry at least in the contact row

Comment: @balexandre .   Changing my entire DAL layer to use a different ORM at this timeisn't really an option unfortunately.

Comment: It's hard to give you a definitive answer, but count me in amongst those that vote for option 3  :)

Comment: @Phil roughly how many rows are you expecting to be returned by these calls?

Comment: 10,000 ~60,000 rows in the user table is a conservative estimate.  then 2 or 3 rows in the contact table for each user from there on.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder why you want combine the data.

You already have a `IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts` property in your class.

You only need use the include method on your LINQ call.

```
var lUsers = from usr in dbcontext.User.Include(t => t.Contacts)
             select usr;
```

Comment: There's no mention of Entity Framework in his question.